# Changing instance name for multiple text input boxes

Tags: flash, instances, inputbox

HI i am new to flash scripting and i find it annoying when i have to type instance for a number of text input boxes. Is there any extension where i can change the instance name for all the boxes in 1 shot?

Comment: There is no Adobe supplied extension that allows for this behavior because it is a practice that you should not be following. In fact if you set multiple objects on the stage to the same instance name, any code you try to run against _that_ instance name will only apply to one of the objects on the stage with that instance name, not all of them.  I've tested this in Adobe Flash CC 2014 and multiple objects with the same instance name fail to update homogeneously when they all have the same instance name.

Comment: yes what you said is correct, but i was wondering if there is anything that can automatically rename those names the one like the library renamer extension we use for renaming the symbol names inside library.